# React native ios push notification not working on firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, apple-push-notifications

I am working on a react native project, I get this message when I run the ios app. Push notification works fine on android.

[Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '773162100463'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.

this is the version
react-native: 0.66.3
@react-native-firebase/app: ^13.1.0
@react-native-firebase/messaging: ^13.1.0

Comment: Have you added Push Notification capability for you target? *Tip: always test push notifications on real iOS device as they don’t work on simulator.*

Comment: I have added the push notification capability to the target. I also tested it on a real iOS device, It still didn't work.

Comment: Okay different things can cause this issue such as the Background modes not enabled or .p8 missing from firebase console... Can you confirm if all steps from this guide were completed on your project: https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup ?

Comment: I have all these in place, the notification has been working all the while in react-native-firebase v4. I started noticing this issue since I upgraded to v13